# Trouble getting getItem on an object in a RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm currently having some trouble `getItem` in the RecyclerAdapter on my Photo class. I tried adding

```
public int getItem(int pos){
    return getItem(pos);
}
```

but that did not seem to work it. How can i `getItem(position)` without it having errors? (*If i have not elaborated enough please say.*)

Here is my code so you can tell me what i am doing wrong.

**ViewProfilePostsAdapter.java**

```
public class ViewProfilePostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewProfilePostsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";

private String[] mDataSet;
private int[] getItemIn;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int mLayoutResource;
private Context mContext;
private DatabaseReference mReference;
private String currentUsername;

private Photo mPic;



public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //private final TextView textView;

    ImageView mProfileImage;
    String likesString;
    TextView username, timeDelta, caption, likes, liked;
    ImageView postImage;
    ImageView heartRed, heartWhite;

    UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings();
    User user = new User();
    StringBuilder users;
    String mLikesString;
    boolean likeByCurrentUser;
    Heart heart;
    GestureDetector detector;
    Photo photo;

    public ViewHolder(View convertView) {
        super(convertView);

        if(convertView == null) {
            username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
            postImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            caption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_caption);
            timeDelta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_time_posted);
            likes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLikesString);
            mProfileImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_profile_image);
            heartRed = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_heart_red);
            heartWhite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_heart_white);
            heart = new Heart(heartWhite, heartRed);
            liked = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likeText);
        }
    }

}

public ViewProfilePostsAdapter(String[] dataSet, int[] intSet) {
    mDataSet = dataSet;
    getItemIn = intSet;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_post_listitem, viewGroup, false);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

    viewHolder.photo = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.detector = new GestureDetector(mContext, new GestureListener(viewHolder));

    getCurrentUsername();

    getLikesString(viewHolder);

    viewHolder.caption.setText(getItem(position).getCaption());

    String timestampDifference = getTimestampDifference(getItem(position));
    if(!timestampDifference.equals("0")){
        viewHolder.timeDelta.setText(timestampDifference + " DAYS AGO");
    }else{
        viewHolder.timeDelta.setText("TODAY");
    }

    final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(getItem(position).getImage_path(), viewHolder.postImage);


    //get the profile image and username
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
            .equalTo(getItem(position).getUser_id());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: OnDataChange ******************************************************************************");
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: "
                        + singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getUsername() + "****************************");

                holder.username.setText(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getUsername());


                imageLoader.displayImage(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getProfile_photo(),
                        holder.mProfileImage);

                holder.settings = singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Query userQuery = mReference
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
            .equalTo(getItem(position).getUser_id());
    userQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " +
                        singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUsername());

                viewHolder.user = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.length;
}

public int getItem(int pos){
    return getItem(pos);
}



public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

    ViewHolder mHolder;
    public GestureListener(ViewHolder holder) {
        mHolder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDoubleTap: double tap detected.");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
                .child(mHolder.photo.getPhoto_id())
                .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes));
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
{

                    String keyID = singleSnapshot.getKey();

                    //case1: Then user already liked the photo
                    if(mHolder.likeByCurrentUser &&
                            singleSnapshot.getValue(Like.class).getUser_id()
                                    .equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())){

                        mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
                                .child(mHolder.photo.getPhoto_id())
                                .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
                                .child(keyID)
                                .removeValue();
                    mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
                                .child(mHolder.photo.getUser_id())
                                .child(mHolder.photo.getPhoto_id())
                                .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
                                .child(keyID)
                                .removeValue();

                        mHolder.heart.toggleLike();
                        getLikesString(mHolder);
                    }
                    //case2: The user has not liked the photo
                    else if(!mHolder.likeByCurrentUser){
                        //add new like
                        addNewLike(mHolder);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    //add new like
                    addNewLike(mHolder);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return true;
    }
}

private void addNewLike(final ViewHolder holder){
    Log.d(TAG, "addNewLike: adding new like");

    String newLikeID = mReference.push().getKey();
    Like like = new Like();
    like.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

    mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
            .child(holder.photo.getPhoto_id())
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
            .child(newLikeID)
            .setValue(like);

    mReference.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
            .child(holder.photo.getUser_id())
            .child(holder.photo.getPhoto_id())
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes))
            .child(newLikeID)
            .setValue(like);

    holder.heart.toggleLike();
    getLikesString(holder);
}

private void getCurrentUsername(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentUsername: retrieving user account settings");
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
            .equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                currentUsername = singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getUsername();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void getLikesString(final ViewHolder holder){
    Log.d(TAG, "getLikesString: getting likes string");

    try{
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_photos))
                .child(holder.photo.getPhoto_id())
                .child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_likes));
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                holder.users = new StringBuilder();
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
{

                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    Query query = reference
                            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                            .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
                            .equalTo(singleSnapshot.getValue(Like.class).getUser_id());
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found like: " +
                                        singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUsername());

                                holder.users.append(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUsername());
                                holder.users.append(",");
                            }

                            String[] splitUsers = holder.users.toString().split(",");

                            if(holder.users.toString().contains(currentUsername + ",")){
                                holder.likeByCurrentUser = true;
                            }else{
                                holder.likeByCurrentUser = false;
                            }

                            int length = splitUsers.length;
                            if(length == 1){
                                holder.likesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0];
                            }
                            else if(length == 2){
                                holder.likesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                        + " and " + splitUsers[1];
                            }
                            else if(length == 3){
                                holder.likesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[1]
                                        + " and " + splitUsers[2];

                            }
                            else if(length == 4){
                                holder.likesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[1]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[2]
                                        + " and " + splitUsers[3];
                            }
                            else if(length > 4){
                                holder.likesString = "Liked by " + splitUsers[0]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[1]
                                        + ", " + splitUsers[2]
                                        + " and " + (splitUsers.length - 3) + " others";
                            }
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: likes string: " + holder.likesString);
                            //setup likes string
                            setupLikesString(holder, holder.likesString);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
{

                        }
                    });
                }
                if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    holder.likesString = "";
                    holder.likeByCurrentUser = false;
                    //setup likes string
                    setupLikesString(holder, holder.likesString);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getLikesString: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() 
);
        holder.likesString = "";
        holder.likeByCurrentUser = false;
        //setup likes string
        setupLikesString(holder, holder.likesString);
    }
}

private void setupLikesString(final ViewHolder holder, String likesString) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupLikesString: likes string:" + holder.likesString);

    if (holder.likeByCurrentUser) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupLikesString: photo is liked by current user");
        holder.liked.setText("UnLike");
        holder.heartWhite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.heartRed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.heartRed.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return holder.detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupLikesString: photo is not liked by current user");
        holder.liked.setText("Like");
        holder.heartWhite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.heartRed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.heartWhite.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return holder.detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }
    holder.likes.setText(likesString);

}


//---------------------------------------------end of likes----------------------------

private String getTimestampDifference(Photo photo){
    Log.d(TAG, "getTimestampDifference: getting timestamp difference.");

    String difference = "";
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.CANADA);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Pacific"));//google 'android list of timezones'
    Date today = c.getTime();
    sdf.format(today);
    Date timestamp;
    final String photoTimestamp = photo.getDate_created();
    try{
        timestamp = sdf.parse(photoTimestamp);
        difference = String.valueOf(Math.round(((today.getTime() - timestamp.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 )));
    }catch (ParseException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getTimestampDifference: ParseException: " + e.getMessage() );
        difference = "0";
    }
    return difference;
}
}
```

**Photo.java**

```
public class Photo implements Parcelable {

private String caption;
private String date_created;
private String photo_id;
private String user_id;
private String tags;
private String image_path;
private List<Like> likes;


public Photo(){

}

public Photo(String caption, String date_created, String photo_id, String user_id, String tags, String image_path, List<Like> likes) {
    this.caption = caption;
    this.date_created = date_created;
    this.photo_id = photo_id;
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.tags = tags;
    this.image_path = image_path;
    this.likes = likes;
}

protected Photo(Parcel in) {
    caption = in.readString();
    date_created = in.readString();
    photo_id = in.readString();
    user_id = in.readString();
    tags = in.readString();
    image_path = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Photo> CREATOR = new Creator<Photo>() {
    @Override
    public Photo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Photo(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Photo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Photo[size];
    }
};

public String getCaption() {
    return caption;
}

public void setCaption(String caption) {
    this.caption = caption;
}

public String getDate_created() {
    return date_created;
}

public void setDate_created(String date_created) {
    this.date_created = date_created;
}

public String getPhoto_id() {
    return photo_id;
}

public void setPhoto_id(String photo_id) {
    this.photo_id = photo_id;
}

public String getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(String tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}

public String getImage_path() {
    return image_path;
}

public void setImage_path(String image_path) {
    this.image_path = image_path;
}

public List<Like> getLikes() {
    return likes;
}

public void setLikes(List<Like> likes) {
    this.likes = likes;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Photo{" +
            "caption='" + caption + '\'' +
            ", date_created='" + date_created + '\'' +
            ", photo_id='" + photo_id + '\'' +
            ", user_id='" + user_id + '\'' +
            ", tags='" + tags + '\'' +
            ", image_path='" + image_path + '\'' +
            ", likes=" + likes +
            '}';
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(caption);
    parcel.writeString(date_created);
    parcel.writeString(photo_id);
    parcel.writeString(user_id);
    parcel.writeString(tags);
    parcel.writeString(image_path);
}
}
```

Comment: What this function does? Is it calling itself   public int getItem(int pos){
    return getItem(pos);
} Function also should return obect instead of int.

Comment: So from what i understand that you're saying is changing the `int` after public in `public int getItem(int pos){
        return getItem(pos);
    }` to `Object`, so that it returns an object. If that's the case, it does not work :P

Comment: Are u able to understand what this function it does??  public int getItem(int pos){ return getItem(pos); }

Comment: An example is here for better understanding:  public Message getItem(int position) {
  return messageList.get(position);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function  calls itself:

```
public int getItem(int pos){
    return getItem(pos);
}
```

To fix the problem you should do several things:
1) You adapter should have collection of Photo objects. E.g. ArrayList list;

It should be filled from maybe Countructor. So, your adapter should have constructor containing this list.

2) Change getItem method to this :

```
public Photo getItem(int pos){
    return list.get(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your getItem function should return an object (i guess).
Also Honestly I am little confused what u r trying to accomplish and I thought You wanted to get an item in a specific position in your recycler view right?

> In your Viewholder class just add below code

```
  int position = 0;
```

> In your OnBindViewHolder Function in the RecyclerViewAdapter, there is a position of each item in your recyclerview

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Model yourModel= modelList.get(position);


    holder.position = position;



}
```

> Besides if you are trying to get OnClickListener in your recyclerview. The Following way may be useful. Create Interface

```
public interface RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener {

void OnItemClickListener(View view, int position);
void OnItemLongClickListener(View view, int position);
```

}

> This code goes into RecyclerAdapter Class

```
    public  void  setOnItemClickListener(RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener OnItemClickListener){
    this.recyclerViewOnItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener;
}
```

> Final Step in your Main activity or your fragment that you wanna show the recyclerview

```
recyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClickListener(View view, int position) {
            Model yourModel= modelList.get(position); 

        }

        @Override
        public void OnItemLongClickListener(View view, int position) {

        }
    });
```

Here is how you can get the item in a specific position.
Hope this helps ;)